# How to solve Error creating Service: googleapi: Error 403: Permission 'iam.serviceaccounts.actAs' denied on service account

Tags: terraform, google-cloud-run, service-accounts, terraform-provider-gcp, google-iam

I've been trying to create a public cloud run invoker policy and bind that to my cb_app cloud run service so that it can be exposed. I've created a custom service  and assigned it cloud admin role. But getting this error

`Error: Error creating Service: googleapi: Error 403: Permission 'iam.serviceaccounts.actAs' denied on service account app-worker@samuel-django-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com (or it may not exist).`

Here are the configs

```
resource "google_cloud_run_service_iam_member" "domain" {
  service = google_cloud_run_service.cb_app.name
  location = google_cloud_run_service.cb_app.location
  role = "roles/run.admin"
  member = "serviceAccount:${var.service_account}" 
}
#create service account to run service
resource "google_service_account" "cb_app" {
    account_id    = "app-worker"
    display_name  = "app worker"
}
```

And in app service, I have this

```
spec {
      # Use locked down Service Account
      service_account_name = google_service_account.cb_app.email
```

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: What is the content of ${var.service_account}?

Answer (score 7):

When you create a resoure such as Cloud Run, you have the option to attach a service account to the resource.

The following error means that the identity (user or service account) that Terraform is using does not have permission to attach the service account to the resource.

> Error: Error creating Service: googleapi: Error 403: Permission
> 'iam.serviceaccounts.actAs' denied on service account
> app-worker@samuel-django-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com (or it may
> not exist).

The solution is to add the role **roles/iam.serviceAccountUser** to the identity that Terraform is running under. You do not specify the identity in your question. The identity could be a user account or a service account. Go to the Google Cloud Console -> IAM. Find the identity and add the role.

You can also use the CLI **gcloud**. The exact command arguments depend on the identity type.

**For a user account**:

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding PROJECT_ID \
--member='user:someone@gmail.com' \
--role='roles/iam.serviceAccountUser'
```

**For a service account**:

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding PROJECT_ID \
--member='serviceAccount:myserviceaccount@PROJECT_ID.iam.gserviceaccount.com' \
--role='roles/iam.serviceAccountUser'
```

The above commands use Linux syntax. For Windows replace **\** with **^**

Comment: Be aware that by using PROJECT_ID as the resource to which you are binding the policy, you are telling google cloud to allow the MEMBER to act as ANY service account in the project. That may be more power than you want to delegate.  You can also add the policy binding to a specific service account within the project. To do that, replace `PROJECT_ID` in the above example commands with the full email of the Service account, eg `SA_NAME@PROJECT_ID.iam.gserviceaccount.com` .

Comment: @Cheeso - yes you are correct. A service account is both an identity and a resource. Impersonation is an important factor in security design. Can you move your comment to the question so that more people will notice it?

Comment: In my case, I was using a Pulumi service account to deploy a CloudRun service using Pulumi. I needed to add the `Service Account User` role to the Pulumi service account and then it worked!

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution to this issue if you're encountering it while **applying Terraform in Google Cloud Shell**.

I also encountered a very similar error:

```
Error: googleapi: Error 403: Missing necessary permission enter code hereiam.serviceAccounts.actAs for $MEMBER 
on the service account mr-service-account-sa@mr-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com. 
Grant the role 'roles/iam.serviceAccountUser' to $MEMBER on the service  
account mr-service-account-sa@mr-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com. 
You can do that by running 'gcloud iam service-accounts 
add-iam-policy-binding mr-service-account-sa@mr-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com --member=$MEMBER 
--role=roles/iam.serviceAccountUser'. 
In case the member is a service account please use the prefix 'serviceAccount:' instead of 'user:'.
```

I think this error message is deceptive/misleading.

My solution:

- **was not** to give the "Service Account User" role to mr-service-account-sa@mr-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com
- **was not** to give the "Service Account User" role to the Terrform deployment service account.
- **was** to give the "Service Account User" role to my own personal GCP account.

It seems like Cloud Shell uses a mixture of authorisation accounts when applying Terraform.  In some cases it uses the service account defined in the provider and at other times it uses your own GCP OAuth account.

Answer (score 1):

I ran this code:

```
gcloud config set auth/impersonate_service_account [SA_FULL_EMAIL]
```

and it worked for me.